# First fire event and then go to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have something like this im my project:

```
<input onchange="doSomething();" .... />

<a href="url" ... ></a>
```

If input field is focused and I click 'a' link, the browser goes to URL and the event onchange fires only after that. But I want at first to run function "doSomething()" and only then go to the url. How to solve it better?

Answer (score 1):

remove the inline javascript and use jQuery. Preferably you would add some ID's or classes to those elements to target them.

```
$('input').on('change', doSomething);

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     doSomething();
     document.location.href = this.href;
});
```

Assuming `doSomething()` is not asynchronous, as that would be completely different.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this with jQuery (Not tested)

```
<a href="#">..</a>

$('a').click(function(){
    dosomething();
    $(this).attr('href', 'url');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of onchange event, use onblur at Input.

```
<input onblur="doSomething();" type="text" />
<a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a>
```

Test the demo from `http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaarat/V3wT9`
if requirement can be satisfied with javascript only then why to create overhead of jquery ?
Please let me know reason for downvote